# My Android App's Notifications doesn't work on Android 12

Tags: android, kotlin, notifications, android-12

I am trying to display notification using WorkManager and Channels in Kotlin. They are working totally fine on devices with older Androids, I've tested it on Android 8 and Android 11.

But as I try them on Android 12 device (Realme 8) they refuse to show up. I've already tried to change Notification priority, check if the notifications are allowed on my device, tune up the notification volume, nothing helps. I also tested it on different Realme 8 device with Android 12 and also Android emulator version of Pixel XL which is also Android 12 and they didn't work on these devices as well

Other app's notifications work correctly. Only my App's doesn't work on the Android 12 devices[image].

If any more info needed, just say. Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent

If your app targets Android 12 or higher, you must specify the mutability of each PendingIntent object that your app creates. To declare that a given PendingIntent object is mutable or immutable, use the PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE flag, respectively.

PendingIntent.getActivity(requireContext(), 0, Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As vincent091 commented...

The **SOLUTION** for this problem is this:

To declare that a given `PendingIntent` object is mutable or immutable, use the `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` or `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` flag, respectively.

```
PendingIntent.getActivity(requireContext(), 0, Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
```

Comment: Thanks. This was it in my case. I would also like to note that when upgrading to Android 12 you should also set android:exported on all activities, providers, services and receivers in the Android.manifest files.