# Why don't the notification icon of the app display when I run the app in Android API 33?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I use the following code to display a notification icon, it works well when I run the app in  Android  API 30.

I find that the notification icon doesn't dsiplay when I  run the app in  Android  API 33.

I guess that the system maybe block notification, so I open the *Setting* UI, but I find that I couldn't enable the notification of the app, you can set Image A, why?

BTW,  I can enable the notification of my other app in API 33.

**Code A**

```
     private fun startForegroundService() {
        val builder = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {         
            val  mChannelName = getString(R.string.app_name)
            val notificationManager = this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

            val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                mChannelName,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW 
            )
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this, notificationChannel.id)
        } else {
            NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        }

        val myIntent = Intent(this, ActivityMain::class.java)
     
        myIntent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
       
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )

        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notify_icon)            
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.notificationTitle))
            .setTicker(getString(R.string.notificationTicker ))   
            .setContentText(getString(R.string.notificationContent))
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val notification = builder.build()      
        notification.flags = notification.flags or NotificationCompat.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT or NotificationCompat.FLAG_NO_CLEAR
        startForeground(125, notification)
    }


    private fun stopForegroundService() {
        stopForeground(true)
    }


 android {
    compileSdk 33
    flavorDimensions "default"
    namespace 'com.hicalc.soundrecorder'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hicalc.soundrecorder"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
       ...
 }
```

**Image A**

[image]

Comment: do you have perm in manifest? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />` what is your target? (if 33+ then this perm may be mandatory for feature)

Comment: Not a direct answer to the question, but most relevant behaviour changes between Android versions are documented as e.g. [here for Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12) and [here for Android 13](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/13).

Comment: I'd take a look at the `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE/IMMUTABLE` issue mentioned in [My Android App's Notifications doesn't work on Android 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72521009/my-android-apps-notifications-doesnt-work-on-android-12) and in the Android documentation: [https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters#DeclareMutabilityPendingIntent)

Comment: Is there anything interesting in Logcat when the notification should be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

From Android 11, notifications require a valid Notification Channel to be set explicitly.

try by replacing this code for `val notificationChannel` below:-

```
val notificationChannel = NotificationChannel(
    CHANNEL_ID,
    mChannelName,
    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
)
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel)
NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
```